# Make a dconf backup a logout/reboot/shutdown

Tags: scripting, fedora, gnome, dconf

I'm trying to run a script that makes d dump of my dconf every time I logout from gnome-shell on fedora 36 including shutdown and reboot).

For the moment I solved the problem partially by calling my backup script from /etc/gdm/PostSession/Default. After some tweaks with selinux it works fine when I logout. But the script is not called when I shutdown or reboot my machine.

Are there any solutions to run a script everytime a user ends its session?